# Smooth crouch in minecraft bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

You know how in Java Edition when you crouch, it smoothly transitions downwards and then back up. Does anyone know how to get that smooth crouch animation in Bedrock? I've been trying for a long time.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Is there even a difference really? I wouldn't have thought so

Comment: yes theres a difference if you crouch on both versions. In bedrock its almost like choppy but in java its smoother. Its been a while since i posted this and still havent found any packs that can do that